# После cancelTokenSource.Cancel() , Task остается в состоянии RanToCompletion

Tags: c#, task, token

Пытаюсь правильно прервать выполнение функции через token, однако task остается всегда в состоянии RanToCompletion. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
    int number = 6;
    Task task1 = new Task(() =>
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }
            result *= i;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    },cancelTokenSource.Token);
    task1.Start();
    task1.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(task1.Status));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы Task был в состоянии Canceled необходимо было обработать исключение пользовательским кодом, информацию нашел [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/168669/). Получился такой код, который выдает Task.Status = Canceled:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            double a = 5;
            double b = 3;
            Sum(token, a, b);

        }, cancelTokenSource.Token);

        task.Start();
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
        //пользовательская обработка исключения
        }
        finally
        {
            cancelTokenSource.Dispose();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Sum(CancellationToken cancellationToken, double a, double b)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        double s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                s = a + b;
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Для того, чтобы таск перешёл в состояние `Cancelled`, вам необходимо не мягко опросить токен и выйти, а жёстко бросить исключение. Замените

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    return;
}
```

на

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Исключение будет доставлено в `task1.Wait()`, так что вам понадобится ещё try/catch.

Comment: А почему нельзя заменить task.Wait() на await и ловить OperationCancelledException, без генерации исключения в самом таске? Это вопрос.

Comment: @vusaldev: Да, конечно, так было бы лучше. Идиоматический код — это не `new Task()` + `.Start()` + `.Wait()`, а `Task.Run` + `await`. Но в любом случае чтобы состояние `Task`'а было `Canceled`, нужно `Task.Run(код, ct)` + внутри кода `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Иначе `Task` будет в состоянии `RanToCompletion` (если исключение не было выброшено) или `Faulted` (если было). ([Пруф](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,86b4920eb11bc669).)

Comment: Потестил, без ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested и правда не генерится исключение. Как-то это логически неправильно - почему пользователь должен заботиться о прерывании таска внутри таска? Раз await является обёрткой и разворачивается в конечный автомат, было бы неплохо генерить исключение автоматически.

Comment: @vusaldev: Проблема в том, что непонятно, в какой момент безопасно сгенерировать исключение. Вот например, представьте, что вы обновляете двусвязный список, и указатель в одну сторону обновили, а в другую нет. И в этот момент внезапно происходит исключение. Что будет? Список будет в плохом состоянии. Вот и компилятор не может знать, в какой момент можно прерывать выполнение, а в какой нет. Именно поэтому он и не пытается, а перепоручает это нам, программистам.

Comment: спасибо, всё стало понятным.

Comment: @vusaldev: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Если точнее, то это делает так:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
            int number = 6;
            Task task1 = new Task(() =>
            {
                int result = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    result *= i;
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }, cancelTokenSource.Token);
            task1.Start();

            try
            {
                task1.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(task1.Status));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(task1.Status));
            }
```

Comment: Нет никакой необходимости в проверке `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` с этим самостоятельно справляется `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

Comment: @playerone Согласен